# Folder not created on android device

Tags: android, eclipse, file, directory

I take a picture with my android device and in the method onPictureTaken of the classe PictureCallback I have written

```
 File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test");
 imagesFolder.mkdirs();
```

as I want to create a folder in my device's SD Card.

Yet, my folder is not created (it is said the folder was not created, and the folder did not exist)and I have no error on Logcat
How could I possibly test what is going wrong?

(yes I have set the authorization WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE in the Android manifest)

Thank you

Comment: Ok so stupid error from me,just wrote "permision" instead of "permission" in the android manifest, didn't see the warning, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/test");  
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
```